# How can I check the doctype of an html document using Cypress?

Tags: html, automated-tests, cypress

I want to use Cypress to check the doctype of an html document. Specifically I want to make sure the doctype exists and that it is equal to `<!DOCYTPE html>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get it from the `doctype` property of `document`

```js
cy.document().then(doc => {
  expect(doc.doctype !== undefined).to.eq(true)
  expect(doc.doctype.name).to.eq('html')
})
```